# Union all with two rows where first row is empty

Tags: mysql, sql

there is a table where some data is populated and have to get single data for every key value

```
Fk| field1 | field2
====================
 1|r       |lo
2 |abcd    |mem
3 |efghi   |mem
4 |abcd    |mem
5 |efghi   |mem
```

Trying to get single values for every field one which i require

I tried the query:

```
(Select * from table where field1='abd' limit 1)
union all
(Select * from table where field1='abcd' limit 1)
```

I know field1 don't contain 'abd' is not present but it should give me one result right? but it is not giving me.
Expected results

```
Fk| field1 | field2
====================
2 |abcd    |mem
```

If not can you please suggest any better query which can solve my problem.

Edit:- can anyone please share any other query which can give me same result.thanks for helping everyone

Comment: MySql or SQL Server?

Comment: My Sql not server

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue https://dbfiddle.uk/keM5Usa5

Answer (score 0):

In  MySQL 8 you get the wanted results, but your query must be rewritten

```
CREATE TABLE tex
    (`Fk` int, `field1` varchar(5), `field2` varchar(3))
;
    
INSERT INTO tex
    (`Fk`, `field1`, `field2`)
VALUES
    (1, 'r', 'lo'),
    (2, 'abcd', 'mem'),
    (3, 'efghi', 'mem'),
    (4, 'abcd', 'mem'),
    (5, 'efghi', 'mem')
;
```

> ```
> Records: 5  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
> ```

```
(Select * from tex where field1='abd' limit 1 )
union all
(Select * from tex where field1='abcd' limit 1)
```

| Fk | field1 | field2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | abcd | mem |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/4wDMlqsR)

Answer (score 0):

When you use `LIMIT` in a *combinable subquery* for `UNION ALL` all of them except for the last one need to be enclosed in parenthesis.

In this case you want each subquery to limits its results separately, so all of them need to be enclosed in parenthesis.

For example:

```
(Select * from t where field1 = 'abd' limit 1) 
union all
(Select * from t where field1 = 'abcd' limit 1)
```

Result:

```
Fk  field1  field2
--  ------  ------
2   abcd    mem
```

See running example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/6Y1AXXtL).

Comment: Older versions of MySQL (5.6 and before) accept the questioner's syntax. 5.7 and 8.0, and MariaDB 10.3+ reject it, demanding the parentheses.

Comment: That didn't helped but thanks for the information 

Comment: @NavjyotiRath Wasn't this the exact result you wanted?

Comment: Yes, but it's still not working for me. Can you please suggest likewise query which can provide me same answer

Comment: Whn you say that it doesn't work for you, are you talking about the fiddle in the answer or another environment? Can you reproduce the case in a fiddle?

Comment: Other environment